# How to use PDO Prepared statements within a PHP Child Class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm losing my mind a little bit. I have two classess `Database` and `Medication [extends Database]`.

Class Database is a singleton class that constructs my PDO statement:

```
protected function __construct()
{
    require_once(PRIVATE_PATH . "/config/db_credentials.php");
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $pdo) {
        exit("PDOException: " . $pdo->getMessage() . "<br><br>");
    }
}
```

Connection works great, and non-prepared statements work great using it's query method:

```
protected function query($sql)
{
    try {
        $results = $this->conn->query($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $pdo) {
        exit("PDOException: " . $pdo->getMessage());
    }
    return $results;
}
```

In Medications, I am trying to protect my data as much as possible, so I'm trying to do prepared statements:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->conn = Database::getInstance();
}

public function edit_med_by_keyID($keyID, $attributes)
{
    try {
        $attributes['keyID'] = (int) $keyID;
        $sql = "UPDATE medications 
                SET `rxID` = :rxID,
                    `name` = :name,
                    `aka` = :aka,
                    `dosage` = :dosage,
                    `instructions` = :instructions,
                    `prescriber` = :prescriber,
                    `specialty` = :specialty,
                    `category` = :category,
                    `type` = :type,
                    `status` = :status,
                    `notes` = :notes
                WHERE `keyID` = :keyID LIMIT 1";
        $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    } catch (PDOException $pdo) {
        exit("PDOException: " . $pdo->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        exit("Exception: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    return;
}
```

When I try and use this method, it returns the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare()

Part of me understands that this is because my Database class does not have a prepare method in it. On the other hand, PDO does... [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

So my question is - how do I utilize prepared statements from inside a child class of my Database class.

Also, as an FYI - I'm going to be adding more Classes as child classes of Database, which is why I'm trying to do it this way.

I'm also aware there's no ->execute(array()) in there. I'm trying to nail down part one of the issue before I extend it to execute.

Comment: Your database has a `conn` property that does have the prepare statement. So since you store the DB instance in `$this->conn`, you'd access the DB's prepare function with `$this->conn->conn->prepare()` but if `Medications` is extending `Database`, then I'd suggest eliminating `Medications` constructor completely, and it should have access to `$this->conn->prepare()`

Comment: Your edited comment makes more sense.. $this->conn->conn->prepare didn't work, but I'll try removing the Medication __construct()

Comment: Ah that didn't work either because I have Database as a singleton class.. I'll have to switch that up to just have static methods maybe.

Comment: If you're just going to exit in all the catch blocks, why bother? Just skip all the try/catch wrappers and you'll have shorter cleaner code that behaves the same.

Comment: Not part of the question, but I appreciate the callout. I've switched them to die() for now.

Comment: Don't "switch". Just remove every single try..catch from this code. Please read [here](https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#error_reporting) to understand why it's deliberately wrong.

Comment: Instead of creating your own database class in order to create a query function that supports execute(), you can extend PDO. It will let you use every PDO method along with your own function. See [example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#Extending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singletons are both global state, which causes difficult-to-debug issues, and locks you into only ever being allowed to have a single DB connection *ever*. Plus, for some reason you're trying to wrap all the functions that you could possibly call on a PDO object for no reason.

1. Don't wrap the PDO object. It's already an object. Wrapping it again is like putting a hat on a hat.
2. Send the PDO object into the object via constructor arguments. [This is called Composition

Eg:

```php
class Foo {
  public function __construct(protected \PDO $dbh) {}

  public function doThing($args) {
    foreach($args as $arg) {
      $b = new Bar($this->dbh);
      yield $b->something($arg);
    }
  }

}

class Bar {
  public function __construct(protected \PDO $dbh) {}

  public function something($arg) {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare(...);
    $stmt->execute([$arg]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
}

$dbh = new PDO(...);
$f = new Foo($dbh);
$f->doThing([1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: I had a feeling the PDO inside the constructor was going to be the problem. I've seen people do it with mysqli but never with PDO. I was thinking of switching out of PDO because of this, but I like your answer better.

Comment: PHP development has a lot of baggage from "the bad old days" when OOP was new and we hadn't learned our lessons the hard way yet, plus the internet is generally bad at removing dated articles and tutorials. "DB wrapper classes" and "singleton DB objects" are relics from those days that keep cropping up, though gradually less frequently.

Comment: I've noticed. I try and ask questions for a modern solution, and then half get closed with those outdated items as answers. As such, I'm always happy when someone answers something with updated information.

Comment: There's a well-regarded set of principles for writing flexible and maintainable Object Oriented code called SOLID, for which this answer focused on the "D" for "Dependency Inversion". There are many articles on the subject, but this one seems reasonably illustrative: https://accesto.com/blog/solid-php-solid-principles-in-php/